# Printing with javascript problems.....div comes as a null string

Tags: javascript, html, printing

I am using a javascript function to print a page.   I keep getting the string as a null value and im not sure how.....here is the code.   The div i have is called divSheet and its set to visible false to begin...when you load information it creates a table in the divSheet and sets it to true. Any ideas why it says the strid in getPrint function is null?  Thank you!

```
            <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="imageBtnPrint" Style="z-index: 100" ImageUrl="~/Images/printerIcon.gif"
                               OnClientClick="javascript:getPrint('divSheet')" ToolTip="Print" />


    function getPrint(strid)  
    {
        var pp = window.open();
        var prtContent = document.getElementById(strid);
        pp.document.writeln('<HTML><HEAD><title>Print Confirmation Sheet</title><LINK href=PrintStyle.css  type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">')
        pp.document.writeln('<LINK href=PrintStyle.css  type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="print"><base target="_self"></HEAD>')
        pp.document.writeln('<body MS_POSITIONING="GridLayout" bottomMargin="0" leftMargin="0" topMargin="0" rightMargin="0">');
        pp.document.writeln('<form method="post">');  
        pp.document.writeln('<TABLE width=100%><TR><TD></TD></TR><TR><TD align=right><INPUT ID="PRINT" type="button" value="Print" onclick="javascript:location.reload(true);window.print();"><INPUT ID="CLOSE" type="button" value="Close" onclick="window.close();"></TD></TR><TR><TD></TD></TR></TABLE>');
        pp.document.writeln(document.getElementById(strid).innerHTML);
        pp.document.writeln('</form></body></HTML>');

    }
```

Comment: could you share the entire page code, the 'divSheet' element is missing above.

Comment: it has too many characters for me to post....ill put a shortened version of it up here.

Comment: <div runat="server" id="divSheet" visible="false" style="width: 100%; height: 600px;
                        background-color: White; overflow: auto"></div>

Comment: And in between the div tag is a couple of tables.....it also has a few nested divs....

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because you are spawning a child window from your main HTML, and the child page cannot access parent's variables directly.

You could set a local variable in the parent HTML to your div's ID, and then from your JS function access it using: `window.opener.<variable name>`

Something like this:
(warning : untested)

```
...
var divId;
function getPrint(strid)  
{ 
    divId = strid;
    var pp = window.open();
    var prtContent = document.getElementById(window.opener.divId);
    ...
    ...
}
```